# How to configure security restrictions for EJB methods in TomEE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

Basically, I can't get @RolesAllowed annotation to work. It seems that the container completely ignores it.

However, isCallerInRole() method works correctly.

Only admins should be able to call the method below, but the method gets called every time, despite the fact that the user has only a "guest" role.

```
@Remote
public interface SomeManager {
    void performImportantTask();
}

@Stateless
@DeclareRoles({"guest", "admin"})
public class SomeManagerBean implements SomeManager {    
    @Resource private EJBContext context;

    @RolesAllowed({"admin"})
    @Override public void performImportantTask() {
        logger.info(context.getCallerPrincipal().getName()); // prints the correct user name

        if (context.isCallerInRole("admin")) {
            logger.info("Is admin"); // doesn't print
        }

        if (context.isCallerInRole("guest")) {
            logger.info("Is guest"); // prints
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this method called, even though the container is clearly aware that the user is not admin?

I also tried to replace @RolesAllowed with @DenyAll and this denies nothing - the method still executes.

This is the realm configuration in server.xml:

```
...
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
                       dataSourceName="securityDS"
                       userTable="users"
                       userNameCol="user_name"
                       userCredCol="user_pass"
                       userRoleTable="user_roles"
                       roleNameCol="role_name"/>
            </Realm>
            ...            
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Most likely, I have some configuration problem, but I don't know where else to look. 
Or maybe I have some misconception here?

I assume that tomcat_users.xml file has nothing to do with DataSourceRealm. 
Still, thinking that I maybe need to define the roles in this file, I added them like this:

```
<tomcat-users ...>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="guest"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

But this didn't change anything in the above scenario.

Relevant documentation:

[TomEE Security Annotations](http://tomee.apache.org/security-annotations.html)

[DataSourceRealm and TomEE DataSource](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/realm-in-tomee/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that an application server may have multiple applications and multiple realms. Each application may be configured to use an specific realm and map realm users and groups to roles in the application.

In your example:

- The `server.xml` is used to [define one or more realms in the server](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/realm-howto.html).
- The `tomcat_users.xml` allows you define users for the default `UserDatabaseRealm` but not the `DataSourceRealm`. These realms apply to web applications.

> How to configure security restrictions for EJB methods in TomEE?

I think that EJBs in TomEE use the [Java Authentication and Authorization (JAAS)](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-jaas.html). You must configure a JAAS realm in the `server.xml` or the `context.xml` and configure the realm using a `login.config` file. You must set the `java.security.auth.login.config` system property to point that file:

---

**An example:** The TomEE [rest-jaas example](https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/master/examples/rest-jaas/) shows an application that uses the `PropertiesLogin` module, i.e. that uses files to store users and passwords.

1. In the command line, you can run something like:

   ```
   set CATALINA_OPTS="Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/login.config"
   ```

   If you run the TomEE using maven, you can define the variable in `<pluing>` inside your `<build>` in the `pom.xml`

   ```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>7.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <configuration>
       <systemVariables>
         <java.security.auth.login.config>${project.build.directory}/apache-tomee/conf/login.config</java.security.auth.login.config>
       </systemVariables>
       <context>ROOT</context>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Configure the JAAS realm in the `login.config`. TomEE examples usually use the `PropertiesLogin` that stores users and passwords in `.properties` files.

   ```
   PropertiesLogin {
       org.apache.openejb.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
       Debug=false
       UsersFile="users.properties"
       GroupsFile="groups.properties";
   };
   ```

   There are OpenEJB examples that use other login modules, for instance the `SQLLogin`:

   ```
   SQLLogin {
       org.apache.openejb.core.security.jaas.SQLLoginModule required
       jdbcURL="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:sqltest"
       userSelect="SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?"
       groupSelect="SELECT username, grp FROM groups WHERE username = ?";
   };
   ```

   If you define multiple realms. You can change the `PropertiesLogin` or `SQLLogin` root names for custom names.
3. Finally, you must configure the JAAS realm in the `server.xml` (or the `context.xml`). For instance, you can include a `<Realm>` inside the `<Engine>` of the `server.xml`.

   ```
   <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" appName="PropertiesLogin"
        userClassNames="org.apache.openejb.core.security.jaas.UserPrincipal"
        roleClassNames="org.apache.openejb.core.security.jaas.GroupPrincipal">
   ```

   The `appName` varies depending on the names you defined in the above `login.config` file. The `userClassNames` and `roleClassNames` vary depending on the JAAS provider.

---

**Other modules:** You can use other JAAS-compatible login modules. There are many included in the standard java and the OpenEJB. You may check:

- The java documentation for [LoginConfig file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html) for information about the standard `JndiLoginModule`,`KeyStoreLoginModule`, `Krb5LoginModule`, `NTLoginModule` and `UnixLoginModule` modules.
- OpenEJB has [other login modules](https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/master/container/openejb-core/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/core/security/jaas), including both mentioned above (`PropertiesLogin` or `SQLLogin`).
- And you can check [the JAAS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASLMDevGuide.html) and create your own login modules.

**Examples:** There are some [TomEE examples](http://tomee.apache.org/examples/index.html) (maven projects) showing how to configure and test components annotated with JAAS (Java Authentication and Authorization), you may check:

- [ejb-examples](https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/master/examples/ejb-examples) includes, among others, a secured EJB.
- [moviefun](https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/master/examples/moviefun) includes unit tests that run with an specific user, and
- [rest-jaas](https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/master/examples/rest-jaas) shows you how to secure REST endpoints.

Comment: Do you mean that DataSourceRealm should not be used with Tomee? I configured it using the Tomcat documentation, thinking that Tomee just uses what Tomcat already has.

Comment: TomEE uses Tomcat for the Web servlets/JSPs and OpenEJB for the EJBs. According to [this old forum](http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Securing-EJB-with-webapp-Realm-td4669071.html), you can use Tomcat-based realms (contextual realms) to secure web applications but not EJBs. You need JAAS to secure EJBs.